# Get list of only latest message in conversations from MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to get a list of the last message in each conversation for o365 mail.

It appears that the odata aggregate extension (http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0.html) is not implemented. In the following query, $apply is just ignored and fails silently.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$select=conversationId,subject,createdDateTime&$apply=groupby(conversationId, topcount(1, createdDateTime))

Is there a way to get just this data without pulling back large amounts of messages and filtering out duplicate conversation ids?

Comment: For clarification, does this mean you don't care if there are other messages that have arrived in the inbox since the last time you ran your query? Did you mean 'filtering out duplicate conversation ids' or did you actually mean duplicate message ids?

Comment: No, I meant conversation ids. Mail messages have conversationId as a property. The problem is that I have a list of messages that includes every message in the conversation. I would like to only display the last message of each conversation in a list and I would prefer to be able to do that without pulling back data that I don't actually need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a last sync date, [according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-messages?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0), you can start tracking changes at an arbitrary date. You may have to deal with duplicate data if your goals can't be supported by a `receivedDateTime` filter.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages/delta?$select=conversationId,subject,createdDateTime&$filter=receivedDateTime+ge+{value}
```